# Affine operator that maps simplex into itself

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, operator-theory

What is the general form of an affine operator $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, $F(x)=Ax+b$ ($A$ is a linear operator, and $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$) that maps the simplex
$$
\Delta=\Big\{x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n:\,\,  x_k\geq 0\,\,\forall k=\overline{1,n},\,\, \sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k=\gamma\Big\}
$$
(where $\gamma>0$) into itself (that is, $F(\Delta)\subseteq\Delta$)?

I proved only that an affine operator that maps the hyperplane
$$
\Gamma=\Big\{x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n:\,\,  \sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k=\gamma\Big\}
$$
into itself has the form $F(x)=Ax+b$ where
$$
A^T a=\Big(1-\frac{\langle a,b\rangle}{\gamma}\Big)a,\quad a=(1,1,\ldots,1)\in\mathbb{R}^n.
$$

Comment: When $b = 0$ these are the stochastic matrices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, is this the only kind of matrices that has this property? Are there any other, "non-stochastic" matrices or affine transforms that map a (unit) simplex onto itself?